# FILTER DATA IN JAVASCRIPT TO DISPLAY SPECIFIC RACE - FETCHED FROM JSON URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently I am using Javascript to fetch JSON data from a URL. I have added the data that I am fetching. The data are horses and their odds for different horse race. I want to filter the data to display a specific race. For example I want to display the Horse no, name & odds for Race 2 only. Where should I add the filter code and how? NOTE: I don't want a filter button. I need to display table containing Race 2 in HTML.

Data from JSON

```json
{
   "date":"2021-06-19",
   "name":"05",
   "races":[
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"1",
            "time":"12H15",
            "name":"THE TOMMY BOY CUP - Valeur [0-25] - 1400 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"TYRANDEUS",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"ZODIAC JACK",
               "odds":"1200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"THE RIGHT STUFF",
               "odds":"650",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"AFTER THE ORDER",
               "odds":"1400",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"DOUBLE WINNER",
               "odds":"3000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"BLEU ROYALE",
               "odds":"430",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"RED FORCE ONE",
               "odds":"200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"TIME IS GOLD",
               "odds":"450",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"2",
            "time":"12H50",
            "name":"THE MTCSPORTSANDLEISURE.COM CUP - Valeur [0-26] - 990 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"FAIRBANKS",
               "odds":"1500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"CLOUD SEEDER",
               "odds":"1200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"COURTROOM MAGIC",
               "odds":"650",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"FOLLOW SUIT",
               "odds":"450",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"MARULA",
               "odds":"220",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"ZENO",
               "odds":"900",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"ZENZERO",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"ARTAX",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"3",
            "time":"13H25",
            "name":"THE WORLD VETERINARY DAY CUP - Valeur Benchmark 31 - 1600 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"AFFRANCHI",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"AFRICAN ROCK",
               "odds":"270",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"IMPERIAL RAGE",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"SENOR'S GUEST",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"CAMP DAVID",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"DREAMFOREST",
               "odds":"900",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"ITALIAN WAY",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"LIT",
               "odds":"1200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"THE GREY CRUSADER",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"OVERDOSE",
               "odds":"3300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"STAR OF ZEUS",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"4",
            "time":"14H00",
            "name":"THE DR. V. PIERRE GOUPILLE CUP - Valeur Benchmark 41 - 1365 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"BOLD PHOENIX",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"CLOUDED HILL",
               "odds":"1400",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"KING OF TARA",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"HIGH VOLTAGE",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"SAVVY",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"VARSIDE",
               "odds":"315",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"YANKEEDOODLEDANDY",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"WHY WOULDN'T YEW",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"5",
            "time":"14H35",
            "name":"THE WORLD FOCUS CUP - Valeur Benchmark 46 - 1500 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"CARBON FIBRE",
               "odds":"2200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"JOHN HANCOCK",
               "odds":"2200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"CYBER SPECIAL",
               "odds":"470",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"DROP KICK",
               "odds":"230",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"SYDS LIASON",
               "odds":"700",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"TRIP TO THE SKY",
               "odds":"430",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"JET STREAM",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"BONNIE PRINCE",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"THE BYZANTINE",
               "odds":"3000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"GIGGIN",
               "odds":"1400",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"SOCKEROO",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"6",
            "time":"15H10",
            "name":"THE GUNNESS GUJADHUR CUP - Valeur Benchmark 66 - 1450 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"MARAUDING",
               "odds":"350",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"STOPALLTHECLOCKS",
               "odds":"1000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"IDEAL SECRET",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"SPECIAL BLEND",
               "odds":"4000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"TOWER OF WISDOM",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"VAR AND AWAY",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"RED MARS",
               "odds":"1700",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"TRIPLE FATE LINE",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"BACKPACKER",
               "odds":"4000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"DYNAMITE JACK",
               "odds":"200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"STREAM AHEAD",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"7",
            "time":"15H45",
            "name":"THE LALDHEER CUP - Valeur Benchmark 36 - 1500 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"APOLLO STAR",
               "odds":"1000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"BOUND BY DUTY",
               "odds":"1000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"DO OR DARE",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"ITDAWNEDONME",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"SAND PATH",
               "odds":"350",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"ALAMEERY",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"BOLLINGER",
               "odds":"1600",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"BORYA",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"G I JOE",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"WELL CONNECTED",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"NAO FAZ MAL",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"8",
            "time":"16H20",
            "name":"THE RAYMOND ANTELME PLATE - Valeur [0-26] - 1600 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"HIGH KEY",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"SUPREME ORATOR",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"CANARY ISLAND",
               "odds":"270",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"RUBY SPIRIT",
               "odds":"450",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"TICKET HOLDER",
               "odds":"1500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"WEST COAST WARRIOR",
               "odds":"470",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"JET PATH",
               "odds":"1800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"DAREDEVIL AVIATOR",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"GREATFIVEEIGHT",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Javascript

```js
    // api url
const api_url = 
      "https://www.smspariazitservices.com/applications/horse-racing-ws/mtc/actions/getDataBKS.php?date=2021-06-19&mno=05";
  
// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
    
    // Storing response
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    // Storing data in form of JSON
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (response) {
        hideloader();
    }
    show(data);
}
// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);
  
// Function to hide the loader
function hideloader() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
// Function to define innerHTML for HTML table
 function show(data) {
        let tab = 
            `<tr>
            <th>Race #</th>
            <th>Race Name</th>
            <th>Race Date</th>
            </tr>`;
        // Loop to access all rows 
        for (let r of data.races) {
            let { race, horses } = r;
            tab += `<tr> 
                <td>${race.number} </td>
                <td>${race.name}</td>
                <td>${race.time}</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Number</td><td>Name</td><td>Odds</td></tr>
            `;
            tab += horses.map( ({number, name, odds})  => `<tr><td>${number}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${odds}</td></tr>`).join();
            tab += `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`;
        }

        // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
        document.getElementById("racing").innerHTML = tab;
    }
```

HTML

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" 
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
       </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Here a loader is created which 
             loads till response comes -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border" 
                 role="status" id="loading">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>ODDS</h1>
        <!-- table for showing data -->
        <table id="racing"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help

Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/ray-smith/pen/wvgXPgE)! to my codepen

This is what I want to achieve [image: Click to view]

[image: Display will be like this]

Comment: You say you only want to display race 2. Then later you say you only want to display race 1. and you don't want a button to be able to change the display / select the race. So what _do_ you want? Your question is confusing and contradictory

Comment: P.s. this seems to have nothing to do with PHP, please remove that tag

Comment: Sorry, I have fix that. All I want to do is to display each race in different DIV/ CONTAINER. On my website, I should be able to display Race1 anywhere I want and Race 2 another place etc probably by adding "table ID" on my html

Comment: So you want to download all the races, and then display each one different places, is that right? Let's say you have a `<table id="race-1"` and `<table id="race-2"` to put them in, as you suggested...are you saying these tables already exist before the racing data is downloaded, and the code should just send each race to the correct numbered table, or are you saying it should create a table for each race it finds in the data? It's still not 100% clear how you want this to work, in detail.

Comment: I apologies that I am unable to be clear enough and I thank you for still taking the time to look into this and help. Yes correct, I want to download all the races, and then display each one on different places. I am actually trying to find the best solution to achieve this, whether sending data to an existing numbered table or create a table for each. I don't know which one will be more suitable but the easiest one will be best. I understand HTML/CSS very well but not too good in JS.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to create the tables as you go along, then you don't have to know in advance how many races are listed in the data. I will work on an answer and add it below

Answer (score 1):

You could add a data-attribute called `data-race="x"` to each `<tr>` in the "Loop to access all rows"

Create a css class

```
tr.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

In your filter function, just add the `.hidden` class to all `<tr>` that dont have the data attribute that you have selected.
When clearing the filter, just remove `.hidden` from all `<tr>`

Here's a quick updated version of your pen with a basic filter: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rohanb10/pen/KKWEjPW)

Comment: thank you for your help with this. I don't want a filter button, I want to display each race in different column(DIV/Container). In my HTML, It should be like  <table id="race1"></table> and it display only race one. Any solution to achieve this?

Comment: I have restructure my question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate table for each race then you just need to amend the HTML which is being generated by the Javascript:

```
function show(data) {
    let tab = "";

    // Loop to access all rows 
    for (let r of data.races) {
        let { race, horses } = r;
        tab += `<table><tr>
        <th>Race #</th>
        <th>Race Name</th>
        <th>Race Date</th>
        </tr><tr> 
            <td>${race.number} </td>
            <td>${race.name}</td>
            <td>${race.time}</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Number</td><td>Name</td><td>Odds</td></tr>
        `;
        tab += horses.map( ({number, name, odds})  => `<tr><td>${number}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${odds}</td></tr>`).join();
        tab += `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>`;
    }

    // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
    document.getElementById("races").innerHTML = tab;
}
```

And then you would replace

```
<table id="racing"></table>
```

with

```
<div id="races"></div>
```

in the existing HTML, to act as the placeholder.

---

N.B. If this doesn't produce the layout you wanted, you'll need to be more specific about the precise requirement, ideally including a mockup / example.

Comment: This is not changing anything. It still fetch all the data (All the races). Like I said before, I want to add each race on a different container. I have tried added ` let { race, horses } = r;
   if (race.number == 1) {
        tab += `<table><tr>` and the set the elementID as race 1, works well. I wrote another script and add a filter ` let { race, horses } = r;
   if (race.number == 2) {
        tab += `<table><tr>`  and set the elementID as race2. Race 1 stop working.  I have added some new image to better understand.

Comment: `Like I said before, I want to add each race on a different container`...well a table _is_ a type of container. If that's not what you mean then like I said above you'll need to clarify more precisely what you're referring to. "container" isn't a specific HTML element, so please explain if you had a specific element in mind.

Comment: `It still fetch all the data (All the races)`...yes, you said you wanted all the races, but each one in different "containers". You also said you only wanted race 2, but that contradicted your statement about putting each race in a different container (and that seemed to make more sense).

Comment: Looking at your new screenshots, I'm not sure if you've really fully explained the scenario here? Is there some dragging and dropping going on? Or what? I think maybe some context is going to be important.

Comment: No @ADyson, in the page builder, I will add raw HTML. In the Raw HTML, I will call the table. I will link the JS file in the head section of the website. Right now my code is displaying all the races. If I add this on my website, all the races will display one under each other and I don't want this. I want Race1 to Race 4 to display next to each other and below, Race 5 to Race 8 to display next to each other. On the page builder (Screenshot) I have already created to rows of 4 column. On each cell, I will add a raw html to display the race. Cell 1 I will add the html to dispay race1 etc..

Comment: Right so this goes back to the comments above where I asked you `are you saying these tables already exist before the racing data is downloaded, and the code should just send each race to the correct numbered table`...and you said "no", but now you're saying actually there _is_ a place where we need to put this data (even if it may not be a table). So...what are these target elements called? Does each one have a unique ID, containing the number of the race which should go into it?

Comment: You are not getting my point. A page builder is already made of rows and columns and in each cells you can add widgets like Image, text, slideshows, forms, videos etc. In my case I will add Raw HTML to display the race table. To make thing more clear, I want to fetch the data from the JSON and then have a JS and HTML code that allows me to display Race1 on Home Page in the top, Race 2 in the bottom and Race3 on another page on the website. This is not my goal, but if I get the solution of this, it will make me achieve what I need.

Comment: You mean you want to store the data so that the user can then decide which place to put each race, and then it would be placed there based on some user selection event in the UI? Or you want to automatically allocate each race to a certain pre-defined place?

Comment: I will allocate each race to a pre-defined place.

Comment: Ok so if you tell me the IDs of each place then we can write the code to place them there

Comment: I have created a new Question being more accurate. You can check it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113538/display-data-fetched-from-json-in-html-tables-using-javascript-different-part)

Comment: Ok please delete this one then