# Display data fetched from JSON in HTML tables using JavaScript - different part of data in different section on website

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using JScript to fetch data from a JSON API url. (I have added the data in the JSON file below - These are 8 horse races and each races displays Horse number, Horse name and their odds). I am trying to write a Jscript to display each races on individual table inside a container/DIV. I should be able to place each race on different section of the website. Eg. Race1  on home page on the top, Race2 on Home page in the bottom and Race 3 on another place on the website. With my current code, when I add 2 races or more, only one displays. Please note that I am only beginner in Javascript.

Data from JSON

```json
{
   "date":"2021-06-19",
   "name":"05",
   "races":[
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"1",
            "time":"12H15",
            "name":"THE TOMMY BOY CUP - Valeur [0-25] - 1400 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"TYRANDEUS",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"ZODIAC JACK",
               "odds":"1200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"THE RIGHT STUFF",
               "odds":"650",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"AFTER THE ORDER",
               "odds":"1400",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"DOUBLE WINNER",
               "odds":"3000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"BLEU ROYALE",
               "odds":"430",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"RED FORCE ONE",
               "odds":"200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"TIME IS GOLD",
               "odds":"450",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"2",
            "time":"12H50",
            "name":"THE MTCSPORTSANDLEISURE.COM CUP - Valeur [0-26] - 990 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"FAIRBANKS",
               "odds":"1500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"CLOUD SEEDER",
               "odds":"1200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"COURTROOM MAGIC",
               "odds":"650",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"FOLLOW SUIT",
               "odds":"450",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"MARULA",
               "odds":"220",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"ZENO",
               "odds":"900",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"ZENZERO",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"ARTAX",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"3",
            "time":"13H25",
            "name":"THE WORLD VETERINARY DAY CUP - Valeur Benchmark 31 - 1600 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"AFFRANCHI",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"AFRICAN ROCK",
               "odds":"270",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"IMPERIAL RAGE",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"SENOR'S GUEST",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"CAMP DAVID",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"DREAMFOREST",
               "odds":"900",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"ITALIAN WAY",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"LIT",
               "odds":"1200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"THE GREY CRUSADER",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"OVERDOSE",
               "odds":"3300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"STAR OF ZEUS",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"4",
            "time":"14H00",
            "name":"THE DR. V. PIERRE GOUPILLE CUP - Valeur Benchmark 41 - 1365 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"BOLD PHOENIX",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"CLOUDED HILL",
               "odds":"1400",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"KING OF TARA",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"HIGH VOLTAGE",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"SAVVY",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"VARSIDE",
               "odds":"315",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"YANKEEDOODLEDANDY",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"WHY WOULDN'T YEW",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"5",
            "time":"14H35",
            "name":"THE WORLD FOCUS CUP - Valeur Benchmark 46 - 1500 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"CARBON FIBRE",
               "odds":"2200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"JOHN HANCOCK",
               "odds":"2200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"CYBER SPECIAL",
               "odds":"470",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"DROP KICK",
               "odds":"230",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"SYDS LIASON",
               "odds":"700",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"TRIP TO THE SKY",
               "odds":"430",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"JET STREAM",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"BONNIE PRINCE",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"THE BYZANTINE",
               "odds":"3000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"GIGGIN",
               "odds":"1400",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"SOCKEROO",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"6",
            "time":"15H10",
            "name":"THE GUNNESS GUJADHUR CUP - Valeur Benchmark 66 - 1450 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"MARAUDING",
               "odds":"350",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"STOPALLTHECLOCKS",
               "odds":"1000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"IDEAL SECRET",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"SPECIAL BLEND",
               "odds":"4000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"TOWER OF WISDOM",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"VAR AND AWAY",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"RED MARS",
               "odds":"1700",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"TRIPLE FATE LINE",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"BACKPACKER",
               "odds":"4000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"DYNAMITE JACK",
               "odds":"200",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"STREAM AHEAD",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"7",
            "time":"15H45",
            "name":"THE LALDHEER CUP - Valeur Benchmark 36 - 1500 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"APOLLO STAR",
               "odds":"1000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"BOUND BY DUTY",
               "odds":"1000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"DO OR DARE",
               "odds":"550",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"ITDAWNEDONME",
               "odds":"500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"SAND PATH",
               "odds":"350",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"ALAMEERY",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"BOLLINGER",
               "odds":"1600",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"BORYA",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"G I JOE",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"10",
               "name":"WELL CONNECTED",
               "odds":"2000",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"11",
               "name":"NAO FAZ MAL",
               "odds":"-",
               "type":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "race":{
            "number":"8",
            "time":"16H20",
            "name":"THE RAYMOND ANTELME PLATE - Valeur [0-26] - 1600 M \r",
            "ended":"0"
         },
         "horses":[
            {
               "number":"1",
               "name":"HIGH KEY",
               "odds":"300",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"2",
               "name":"SUPREME ORATOR",
               "odds":"800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"3",
               "name":"CANARY ISLAND",
               "odds":"270",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"4",
               "name":"RUBY SPIRIT",
               "odds":"450",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"5",
               "name":"TICKET HOLDER",
               "odds":"1500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"6",
               "name":"WEST COAST WARRIOR",
               "odds":"470",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"7",
               "name":"JET PATH",
               "odds":"1800",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"8",
               "name":"DAREDEVIL AVIATOR",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            },
            {
               "number":"9",
               "name":"GREATFIVEEIGHT",
               "odds":"2500",
               "type":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    // api url
const api_url = 
      "https://www.smspariazitservices.com/applications/horse-racing-ws/mtc/actions/getDataBKS.php?date=2021-06-19&mno=05";
  
// Defining async function
async function getapi(url) {
    
    // Storing response
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    // Storing data in form of JSON
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (response) {
        hideloader();
    }
    show(data);
}
// Calling that async function
getapi(api_url);
  
// Function to hide the loader
function hideloader() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<script>
// Function to define innerHTML for HTML table
 function show(data) {
        let tab = 
            `<tr>
            <th>Race #</th>
            <th>Race Name</th>
            <th>Race Date</th>
            </tr>`;
        // Loop to access all rows 
        for (let r of data.races) {
            let { race, horses } = r;
  if (race.number == 1) {
            tab += `<tr> 
                <td>${race.number} </td>
                <td>${race.name}</td>
                <td>${race.time}</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Number</td><td>Name</td><td>Odds</td></tr>
            `;
            tab += horses.map( ({number, name, odds})  => `<tr><td>${number}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${odds}</td></tr>`).join();
            tab += `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`;
        }}

        // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
        document.getElementById("race1").innerHTML = tab;
    }
</script>

<script>
// Function to define innerHTML for HTML table
 function show(data) {
        let tab = 
            `<tr>
            <th>Race #</th>
            <th>Race Name</th>
            <th>Race Date</th>
            </tr>`;
        // Loop to access all rows 
        for (let r of data.races) {
            let { race, horses } = r;
  if (race.number == 2) {
            tab += `<tr> 
                <td>${race.number} </td>
                <td>${race.name}</td>
                <td>${race.time}</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Number</td><td>Name</td><td>Odds</td></tr>
            `;
            tab += horses.map( ({number, name, odds})  => `<tr><td>${number}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${odds}</td></tr>`).join();
            tab += `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`;
        }}

        // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
        document.getElementById("race2").innerHTML = tab;
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" 
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
       </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Here a loader is created which 
             loads till response comes -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border" 
                 role="status" id="loading">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>ODDS</h1>
        <!-- table for showing data -->
        <table id="race1"></table>
<br>
<table id="race2"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help

Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/ray-smith/pen/wvgXPgE)! to my codepen (Please not the JSON API on codepen is only available at 17:00 (GMT+4)

Comment: When you declare a function twice with the same name, the second declaration overwrites the first. So you only have one `show` function, which is the second one, which only creates a row for race 2. Display all races on a page in the for loop, and load the data and show different races on a different page. Page code will need to supply `show` with values held on the page to say what races and where to put them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove if (race.number == 2)  from your function show and let only one function show. When you call innerHTML method for fill the table you can use race.number for select the corrispondent table. Your code will be:

```
function show(data) {
    
    // Loop to access all rows 
    for (let r of data.races) {
        let { race, horses } = r;
        let tab = 
        `<tr>
        <th>Race #</th>
        <th>Race Name</th>
        <th>Race Date</th>
        </tr>`;
        tab += `<tr> 
            <td>${race.number} </td>
            <td>${race.name}</td>
            <td>${race.time}</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Number</td><td>Name</td><td>Odds</td></tr>
        `;
        tab += horses.map( ({number, name, odds})  => `<tr><td>${number}</td><td>${name}</td><td>${odds}</td></tr>`).join();
        tab += `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`;

        // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
        document.getElementById("race"+race.number).innerHTML = tab;
    }     
}
```

In your html page you can insert table tag with id="race1", id="race2", ecc.
where you want to display each race result

Comment: Good solution. It's also worth pointing out to the OP that it's not valid to have two functions with the same name

Comment: Thank you, This looks very positive. The only part I am confuse is how to insert the ",,ecc", for example, if i want to display Race1 only, how my html should be?

Comment: @ADyson, thank you as well, you did the very best to solve this although my previous question was very confusing in my previous post.

Comment: @SewumberRay thanks. you ask how to only display Race 1, well to understand that, we would first need to know how the code would understand that only race 1 is required, when perhaps at other times all races are required? Is there some input from elsewhere (e.g. from the user) which would indicate that?

Comment: @ADyson, No, I guess this solution has now solved by problem. I will send you a live link so you can see what I wanted to achieve soon.

Comment: If the problem is you don't know how many races you get from API, one solution is write only one div in the html and then add the table tag in the loop. So the function will display one table for each race present in the JSON string, but all the tables will be visible inside the same div.

Comment: Is there any way to force the Race table generated to have 11 rows even with empty cells? The maximum number of horses in the race is 11 and making all table 11 rows will keep it uniform and clean.

Comment: @SewumberRay, yes, get how many horses there are (i.e. size of the horses array), calculate the difference between that and 11 and then add that many rows using a loop, after you've added the horses.

Comment: @ADyson , thank you. I will try to do it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello guys, I have encountered a new issue with this solution. It works fine of Desktop but doesn't work at all on mobile. Could there be any compatibility issue?